# iMacros iimPlay how to call two functions

Tags: javascript, imacros

google.com/I use this iMacros for Firefox and try to make a script to create an element inside a page.

```
var macro;
macro = "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
macro +="SET !TIMEOUT 3"+"\n";
macro +="URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/search?q=a+random+keyword&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"+"\n";
macro +="WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n";

function appendNewHeading() {
    var newHeading = window.content.document.createElement("a");
    newHeading.innerHTML = "<a href='http://www.google.com/' id='kliko'>Link to Click</a>";
    window.content.document.getElementById("rso").appendChild(newHeading);
}
var macro2;
macro2 +="WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n";

for (var i=1;i<3;i++) {
    iimSet("i", i);
    iimPlayCode(macro);
    appendNewHeading();
    iimPlayCode(macro2);
}
```

What am i trying to do here is to go to a website and create a new element ahref, and i want this to be used as a loop so to be played infinitely. Something is wrong with my code the iimPlay(macro); works but the iimPlay(newHeading); is not being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't need to use the `iimPlay()` function in order to call "pure" JavaScript code. So, try something like this:

```
var macro;
macro = "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
macro +="SET !TIMEOUT 3"+"\n";
macro +="URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/search?q=a+random+keyword&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"+"\n";
macro +="WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n";

function appendNewHeading() {
    var newHeading = window.content.document.createElement("a");
    newHeading.innerHTML = "<a href='http://www.google.com/' id='kliko'>Link to Click</a>";
    window.content.document.getElementById("rso").appendChild(newHeading);
}

for ( ; ; ) {
    iimSet("i", i);
    iimPlayCode(macro);
    appendNewHeading();
}
```

Comment: great :) what if i want to add come more functions after appendNewHeading()  do i need only to add example a var macro2; @Shugar

Comment: Sure, you can add `iimPlayCode(macro2)` etc.

Comment: Something is wrong with what i did, i just update my code with var macro2; but when i Play is not playing var macro2;  @Shugar

Comment: Correct the following line like so: `macro2 ="WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n";`.